# Client Connect MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a client-based internet technology that allows me to connect to a remote MYSQL dataabase without using any server side scripting ?

I know that JavaScript does not allow me, but provided that the user knows the database's password, can it be done on the client side?

Comment: Do you _really_ want your clients knowing a database password?

Comment: @user1724140: There are different kinds of "trust."  A client may be trustworthy, may be contractually bound to meet certain standards, etc. but that doesn't mean they should have direct access to internal resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you just need a MySQL administration client?  Something like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) should do the trick, no?  If the database is open and available then any MySQL client application should be able to connect to it, including the command-line tools that come with MySQL.

Keep in mind that, in general, it's usually *not* recommended to expose your database directly to the internet.  You'll want to *really* keep an eye on security if you do this.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply. Is there a technology where this can be done through a browser please

Comment: @user1724140: I've never seen any.  And they would probably require some form of plugin or ActiveX control or something of that nature.  Why does this need to happen inside of a browser if it's not using a server-side web application?  Web browsers generally aren't used as client applications by themselves.  Do you plan to open a local HTML file with an embedded plugin or something?  How are you going to use the web browser for this?

Comment: Thank you... back to the drawing board :)

Comment: @user1724140: There may be other solutions available, but we'll need to know the driving forces behind this.  What you're describing is very non-standard and, as such, it's unlikely that you'd find something that fits the job.  What is the reason for wanting to use a web browser for this if you're not using a web-based application?

Comment: I just thought it would be a good idea to develop a client application using web technology rather than, for example, using c# or java. Everybody has and is familiar with a browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to go with a browser, my first thought is to install a tool like `phpMyAdmin` on the server and then let your users access to that.

Again, I'll give you the same advice the other gave you: don't. Please, don't. And if you **really** want to do that, have a safe backup and take all the necessary precautions.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will be looking into the design as even I don't like it to be honest